# What's D's "out" storage class useful for?

Tags: d

I know that `out` works pretty much like `ref` except that it initializes the passed argument to its default value upon entry into function.

My question is in what situation would this be useful "to reset a variable upon function entry"?

It would be great If someone could show me an example where `out` would be more useful than `ref`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary difference between `ref` and `out` is intention. When `ref` is used, it is expected that the value passed in will be used by the function. And the function may or may not set it. You can even have `const ref` if you want, which would mean that the variable which was passed in wouldn't be copied, but it couldn't be changed either.

`const out`, on the other hand, wouldn't make any sense, because the intention of `out` is that the variable will be set in the function. Using `out` is essentially a way to add another return value to the function. `ref` *could* be used for that, but using `ref` doesn't indicate to the caller that the value being passed in won't be used or even necessarily that the variable will be assigned to, whereas `out` indicates that the value will *not* be used and that the variable *will* be assigned to.

The reason that `out` sets the variable to its default value is to avoid bugs. If the purpose of the function is to use the `out` parameter as another return value, then you generally don't want that function to be affected by the value being passed in. By setting the `out` parameter to its default value, it guarantees that that variable will always be the same value for that function, regardless of what was passed in, so you avoid bugs caused by the function accidentally relying on that value.

Now, there is no requirement that an `out` parameter be assigned to within a function, but it does communicate to the caller that that's the intention, and it *does* assign it the default value regardless, so from the caller's perspective, an `out` parameter is always assigned a value (even if it's the default value). So, the function is free to not set the `out` parameter if that makes sense (e.g. if the default value was what should be "returned" under some set of circumstances).

Answer (score 4):

`out` is similar to `ref`, but it communicates to the caller that you *only* intend to assign a value to the variable inside the function. This is only by convention, but the compiler enforces it somewhat by initializing the variable to its `init` value on function entry, so there's really no point in marking the variable as `out` unless you intend to assign to it.

The compiler does **not** enforce that you must make an assignment to the out parameter during the function, e.g., the following is perfectly legal:

```
void test(out int n)
{
    //Do nothing
}

void main()
{
    int x;
    test(x);
}
```

If you have C background, this is more or less like the common C pattern where a function takes a pointer to a variable so as to initialize it inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Well "out" says that you HAVE to assign the variable something before the function exits. With "ref", not necessarily. I think that's the case, if my memory is not deceiving me. Ref on the other hand, works like reference in C++, you have the option to modify the value or you may leave it as it is.

So, say if you have you are passing some kind of an object to a function that has not been initialize, you can pass it with "out" and have the function accept "out" and in the function you can create that object. However, if the function accepts "ref" and you pass an uninitialized object, I think the compiler will give you an error.

Charles Petzold's .Net Zero book (available for free download) explains all of these delicacies in detail. I suggest you read it.

Comment: But D always initializes data types with a default value, There is no such thing as `uninitialized object` as in C&C++

Comment: well yeah you are right. I have been coding too much C++ lately.:)

Comment: Always is a little strong here. uninitialized objects are possible in D (not in @safe D), with void declarations. int i = void; you basically declare a variable the C way.